# How to fire a select query for this certain tag <m:Number> in XMLTYPE

Tags: sql, database, oracle, xml-parsing, oracle11g

I am using a XMLTYPE column in my table.

My schema is developed on this link on sqlfiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/90306/1

I am able to fetch the value of building using the query there.

But my actual XML is

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/226cf

```
 <m:Building>FBI</m:Building>
```

having a tag like  `<m:Building>` .

But when i am trying to get the value of building here in second schema,i am getting error.

How i can achieve this ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to provide the XML Namespace to the `extract` function, for example:

```
SELECT 
  w.col1.extract
('/House/Building/text()', 'xmlns="rn://dt.com/batch/2010/08/13"').getStringVal()
     "Building"
  FROM tab1 w;
```